# how to get content from Doc file in php

Tags: php, yii2, doc, phpword, phpoffice

how to get content from Doc file in php

i use [PHPOffice/PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) in Yii2.

this Code Dont work: (my Doc File is UTF8)

```
$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($filename, 'MsDoc');
$sections = $phpWord->getSections();
foreach ($sections as $key => $value) {
    $sectionElement = $value->getElements();
    foreach ($sectionElement as $elementKey => $elementValue) {
        if ($elementValue instanceof \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\TextRun) {
            $secondSectionElement = $elementValue->getElements();
            foreach ($secondSectionElement as $secondSectionElementKey => $secondSectionElementValue) {
                if ($secondSectionElementValue instanceof \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Element\Text) {
                    echo $secondSectionElementValue->getText() . '<br/>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i need get content from Doc File (Title,...)

Answer (score 0):

All the text of a .doc file is inside the `[text]` properties nested inside corresponding `[elements]` properties of the object PHPWord creates when loading your .doc file. Search for them in the object you get after running `$phpWord = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($filename, 'MsDoc');` in your code.

These properties by default are protected. You will have to first change their status to `public` in PHPWord library files - for `[elements]` it is AbstractContainer.php, and for `[text]` it is Text.php. Once you have changed the status of these two properties to `public`, you can afterwards extract/access them from your `$phpWord` object.

Comment: Did not work, the $phpWord object does not have these properties.